# Unconfined dispatcher для выполнения корутин

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

В каких "пограничных" случаях может быть использован [`Unconfined dispatcher`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html) для выполнения корутин?

> Unconfined dispatcher is an advanced mechanism that can be helpful in
>   certain corner cases where dispatching of coroutine for its execution
>   later is not needed or produces undesirable side-effects, because some
>   operation in a coroutine must be performed right away.

Насколько я понимаю, это переводится так: "Unconfined dispatcher - это продвинутый механизм, который может быть полезен в некоторых случаях, когда не требуется отправка корутины для ее выполнения позже или она создает нежелательные побочные эффекты, потому что некоторая операция в корутине должна выполняться прямо сейчас."

И правильно ли я понимаю, что это значит, что этот диспетчер следует использовать в случаях, когда не требуется откладывать выполнение корутины c помощью delay или подобных механизмов? И почему далее написано, что Unconfined dispatcher не должен использоваться в общем коде?

А также мне непонятно, каким образом suspending функция определяет поток, в котором после её вызова возобновляется выполнение корутины, определённой с  `Dispatchers.Unconfined`. Пример, приведённой в той же статье:

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) { // not confined -- will work with main thread
        println("Unconfined      : I'm working in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(500)
        println("Unconfined      : After delay in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }  
}
```

вывод:

```
Unconfined      : I'm working in thread main
Unconfined      : After delay in thread kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
```

Каким образом функция `delay()` определила поток для следующего после неё выполнения корутины как `kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы все там прочли?

> The Dispatchers.Unconfined coroutine dispatcher starts coroutine in the caller thread, but only until the first suspension point. After suspension it resumes in the thread that is fully determined by the suspending function that was invoked. Unconfined dispatcher is appropriate when coroutine does not consume CPU time nor updates any shared data (like UI) that is confined to a specific thread.

Иными словами, для задач, не требующий ресурсов и которым без разницы где выполняться. Я так понимаю для экономии на переключении придумано.

Comment: Да, я прочла это. И это в том числе вызвало мой вопрос) Тут написано, что после приостановки корутина возобновляется в потоке, который полностью определяется suspending функцией, которая была вызвана. А вот каким образом определяется, по какому алгоритму? В этом и был мой вопрос)

Comment: Надо смотреть как реализована конкретная suspending функция, в примере используется `delay()`, предположу что она "ждет" на `kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor`, поэтому на нем же продолжается выполнение.

Comment: Но по идее авторов, как я их понял, вас это не должно волновать. Как раз суть `Unconfined dispatcher` в том, что отдали на выполнение, где-то выполнится самым "дешевым" для ресурсов способом.